# How to display user profile information in a modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a table of registered users and would like to display their profile info in a modal
 triggered by clicking on their `<a href="#">name<a>`.

Below is part of the working code via [my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0nIItyNBpyBSNiF6illv)

As in my code above, I'm currently doing the modal using Bootstrap, however I'm converting a lot
of our project to Angular JS. Any JS coders familiar with how to do this?

Thanks in advance
Darold

Comment: Have you checked out [Angular-Bootstrap](http://ngmodules.org/modules/bootstrap)

Comment: Yes I have and actually am just starting to use it - http://angular-ui.github.com/ as well as the UI Bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will answer your question but I have created a plunker demo using AngularJS

http://plnkr.co/edit/bNzolsIIm5geRd05Jaq6

**HTML File code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dynamic User Profile Loading</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table >
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td><a ng-click="getUserProfile(user)">{{user.username}}</a></td>
        <td>{{user.profile.fullName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.profile.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.profile.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.users =[{username: 'first'},{username: 'second'}, {username: 'third'},{username: 'fourth'}];  

  $scope.getUserProfile = function(user){
    //Here we have received the user object so search for the object int he array  
    var inx = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
    if(inx >= 0)
    {
      //retrieve user profile from server. 
      //Here we are going to set some values for the demo purpose
      $scope.users[inx].profile = {}; //Initialize profile as an object
      $scope.users[inx].profile.fullName = user.username + ' user';
      $scope.users[inx].profile.email = user.username + '@example.com';
      $scope.users[inx].profile.phone = user.username + ' phone';

    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I will try this out. I also came across another way of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/qChkF/10/

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about this a couple weeks ago.  My blog post includes a plunkr example of doing pretty much exactly this with a twitter bootstrap modal (and **no** extra UI directives)

http://willvincent.com/blog/angularjs-and-twitter-bootstrap-playing-nicely

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking to do! Will, thanks a million!! Your example is clean and awesome.

Comment: You bet.  Glad it helps :)